# Moving to xcode 4.4 wipes out GPX files in Schemes

Tags: core-location, xcode4.4, gpx

Not only did I lose the references to a particular gpx files in my schemes... I can't add back the files.

When editing the scheme (by adding a gpx file). finder doesn't highlight any gpx files as being eligible.

Thought perhaps this was an iOS file association issue so I moved form lion to mountain lion as a desperate move.  No help

Anyone else come across this ??
thanks